# Javascript D3-fetch write to csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have some code that reads a csv using d3-fetch. I load my csv in the way:

`D3.csv(./mydata.csv).then(function (info) {
Console.log(info);
});`

this works fine and gives me my data. But how would i write to this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind D3 is supposed to be run in a web browser. Web browsers can read files through HTTP but they cannot write files.

A server could write files on a file system it controls. So you would need to write a server endpoint like `/editCSV` and then make a `POST` request to it from the browser. Your server could then write the changes to the CSV file.

In order to do this, you need to have control of the server (for example, a Node.js server) that is serving the CSV and the related file.